# Android using variable for first time

Tags: android, android-sharedpreferences

I need to set some values to their associated persistently stored data, if they exist, on initialization. If not I need to initialize them. Is there any disadvantage to using the SharedPreference to initialize the variable on the first run. That is, something like this :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("MyDataName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String name = sp.getString("name", "");
    boolean isFirstRunning = sp.getBoolean("firstTime", true);

    if (isFirstRunning) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "YEA", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("firstTime", false);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

If there is no disadvantage from a processing level, is there a standard practice as far as this situation is concerned? Also, is there any alternative way to handle the persistent data, or do we have to use SharedPreferences for this?

Comment: sure, it´s easy and fast coding...

Comment: Don't know why you got a down vote for this question. Whether or not it's a good idea really depends on your use-case. If you really need to know if it's the first time your code has ever reached this particular onCreate() function (or has created this activity), I can't see why your solution is 'bad' per-se.

Comment: It's neither good nor bad.

Comment: It's kind of antipattern. Think enterprise, get variables in separated class or method instead.
Note: It's definitely not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that's perfectly acceptable. For neatness it may be better to define the keys, and default values as constants but the approach you have will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

That is based on your requirement. if u need sharedpreference values quickly its good which you wrote. other wise no use.

Comment: is there any other way to do it?